# JavaFx Text fields are not updating on GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to code a memory visualizer that will update a graph with current memory statistics and have a numerical representation just to the side of it. I have an update method that runs in a thread and should update every second.

The issue is that none of it updates on the GUI, and in fact I believe the code stops after one iteration. I believe it has to do with some of the setText() calls because if I comment them out, then at least the graph will update.

Here is my intialize method

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        assert memUsage_lineChart != null : "fx:id=\"memUsage_lineChart\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_totalMem != null : "fx:id=\"text_totalMem\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_usedMem != null : "fx:id=\"text_usedMem\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_availableMem != null : "fx:id=\"text_availableMem\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_percentageUsed != null : "fx:id=\"text_percentageUsed\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_totalRuntime != null : "fx:id=\"text_totalRuntime\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_threadsUsed != null : "fx:id=\"text_threadsUsed\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_version != null : "fx:id=\"text_version\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_timeAtMaxMem != null : "fx:id=\"text_timeAtMaxMem\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_maxMemReached != null : "fx:id=\"text_maxMemReached\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_timeOfLastAssociation != null : "fx:id=\"text_timeOfLastAssociation\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert text_something != null : "fx:id=\"text_totalRuntime\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert lineChart_yAxis != null : "fx:id=\"lineChart_yAxis\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";
        assert lineChart_xAxis != null : "fx:id=\"lineChart_xAxis\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MemoryVisualization.fxml'.";

        runtime = 0L;


        //Initializing the ArrayLists<> that will contain the series of data for each possible graph
        memData = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number,Number>>();       

        //Setting the Y-axis of the chart to change according to incoming data.
        memUsage_lineChart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);

        //Initializes the data arrays and series for the charts 
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series_sec = new XYChart.Series<Number,Number>();
        memUsage_lineChart.getData().add(series_sec);
        memData.add(series_sec);

        //Creates a thread that continuously runs and adds data points to the displays
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runtime += 1000;
                updateData();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }/*END OF INSTANTIATION*/
```

And here is my updateData() method

```
public void updateData()
{
    //Gathers the runtime memory data from the system
    long maxFreeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    long usableFreeMemory= Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
            -Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
            +Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    double usedPercent=(double)(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
            -Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    long usedMemory = (long)(usedPercent*maxFreeMemory);
    maxFreeMemory /= 1000000;
    usableFreeMemory /= 1000000;
    usedMemory /= 1000000;
    usedPercent *= 100;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    //Set the text values for the runtime statistics
    text_totalMem.textProperty().set(String.valueOf(maxFreeMemory));
    text_usedMem.textProperty().set(String.valueOf(usedMemory));
    text_availableMem.textProperty().set(String.valueOf(usableFreeMemory));
    text_percentageUsed.textProperty().set(df.format(usedPercent)+" %");
    text_totalRuntime.textProperty().set((runtime/3600000)+":"+String.format("%02d",((runtime/60000)%60))+":"+String.format("%02d",((runtime%60000)/1000)));
    text_threadsUsed.textProperty().set(String.valueOf(ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount()));

    //Updates the axes of the real-time graphs/charts
    if(runtime >= 120000 && (runtime % 12000) == 0)
    {
        lineChart_xAxis.setLowerBound(lineChart_xAxis.getLowerBound()+12);
        lineChart_xAxis.setUpperBound(lineChart_xAxis.getUpperBound()+12);

        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
            memData.get(0).getData().remove(0);
    }

    //Adds the data to the series to be placed on to the graphs/charts
    memData.get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number,Number>(runtime/1000,usedMemory));
}
```

Is there a reason my GUI gets stuck and wont update the text fields/graph when this is run? I know for a fact that the thread runs at least one iteration since the text fields are not 0 (as initialized) when the GUI pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the `updateData()` method on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater()`. (Additionally, I think the `Thread.sleep(...)` is redundant, since you are using a scheduled executor.)

```
    ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runtime += 1000;
            Platform.runLater(() -> updateData());
        }
    }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```