# JavaFX TextField wont Update Text

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

Basically, I have a pop-up display that has a textfield I want the user to type a name into (then I eventually get the name and use it later but that doesn't matter). Unfortunately, the text in the textfield doesn't update (graphically, the program can still get what was typed through tf.getText(), but I can't see the text updating).

```
    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.setTitle("Naming");
    window.setMinWidth(300);
    window.setMinHeight(200);
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("Please type a name");
    Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setText("Please enter a name");
    tf.setMaxWidth(200);
    submitButton.setOnAction(e ->{
        System.out.println(tf.getText());
        window.close();
    });
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label, submitButton, tf);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.showAndWait();
```

The issue can be fixed through changind `window.showAndWait();` to just `window.show()`, but I'm wondering if it can also be resolved some other way.

Comment: Does this Help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022699/javafx-text-fields-are-not-updating-on-gui)

Comment: The code you provided works well althoug info needed.What Java version you use?Did you call the above code into JavaFX Thread? Are you running any Lock or Thread.sleep() methods that are making the app lag?

Answer (score 0):

The `showAndwait()` method is a blocking call (since it waits), and you are executing this command from the main event loop, blocking handling of events such as repainting the window. `show()` allows to continue and therefore allows this handling. The thing here is that you do not want to wait in the scope you are in, but rather block the original event loop which launched your dialog wait. This could be done by having another scene (a main scene with the main event loop) launch this dialog. Here's an example code demonstrating this:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            // Your snippet
            Stage window = new Stage();
            window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            window.setTitle("Naming");
            window.setMinWidth(300);
            window.setMinHeight(200);
            Label label = new Label();
            label.setText("Please type a name");
            Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
            TextField tf = new TextField();
            tf.setText("Please enter a name");
            tf.setMaxWidth(200);
            submitButton.setOnAction(e ->{
                System.out.println(tf.getText());
                window.close();
            });
            VBox layout = new VBox(10);
            layout.getChildren().addAll(label, submitButton, tf);
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(layout);
            window.setScene(scene2);

            // Root window
            VBox layout2 = new VBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(layout2,400,400);
            Button openButton = new Button("Open");
            openButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                // Launch from action handling thread
                window.showAndWait();

                // Add any logic here like acquiring the entered data from 
                // the window and do interesting stuff with it
            });
            layout2.getChildren().add(openButton);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Launch main window with non-blocking call
            primaryStage.show();


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The `showAndWait()` method is a blocking call (since it waits), and you are executing this command from the GUI thread which makes it not available to repaint the window."* This is only half right. Indeed `showAndWait` blocks, but it enters a nested event loop that updates the UI. BTW: The *"Action Handling thread"* **is the** GUI thread.

Comment: That's correct, when I was talking about thread I was really talking about event loops in the case of JavaFX. I'll edit in consequence, thanks.